# Pesukim for Hilchos Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, tanach, maseches-shabbos

I'm looking for a list  of all the pesukim relevant to learning Hilchos Shabbos. This would preferably include pesukim in Nach. The more thorough the better. It could be either in a well-known sefer or available online.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Chagigah.1.8?lang=bi

Answer (score 3):

My own list (feel free to add if you find more):

1. [Bereishit 2:1-3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.2:1-3?lang=bi)
2. [Shemot 16](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.16:1-36?lang=bi)
3. [Shemot 20:7-10](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.20:8-11?lang=bi)
4. [Shemot 23:12](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.23:12?lang=bi)
5. [Shemot 31:12-17](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.31:12-17?lang=bi)
6. [Shemot 34:21](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.34:21?lang=bi)
7. [Shemot 35:1-3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.35:1-3?lang=bi)
8. [Shemot 36:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.36.6?lang=bi)
9. [Vayikra 23:1-3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Leviticus.23:1-3?lang=bi)
10. [Vayikra 24:5-9](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Leviticus.24:5-9?lang=bi)
11. [Bamidbar 15:32-36](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.15:32-36?lang=bi)
12. [Bamidbar 28:9-10](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.28:9-10?lang=bi)
13. [Devarim 5:11-14](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.5:12-15?lang=bi)
14. [Melachim II 4:23](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Kings.4:23?lang=bi)
15. [Yeshayahu 58:13-14](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.58:13-14?lang=bi)
16. [Yirmeyahu 17:19-27](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jeremiah.17:19-27?lang=bi)
17. [Yechezkel 46:1-5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezekiel.46:1-5?lang=bi)
18. [Nechemiah 10:32](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Nehemiah.10:32?lang=bi)
19. [Nechemiah 13:14-22](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Nehemiah.13:14-22?lang=bi)

Comment: Do any of these count? Yechezkel 20, Yechezkel 44:24, Nechemiah 9:14.  Yeshayahu 56

Comment: @alex Are any of them used to derive hilchot shabbat?